# Js nd css codes integrats in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to integrate js and CSS code elements in a twenty-seventeen WordPress theme. I use enqueue methods but it does not work, so suggest me to all about.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that asking general questions like this is discouraged, questions should only be posted after you have **researched your issue and should include your attempts so far along with the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Please also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Write in `function.php` this code

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
```